# Adding numbers to an array from Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a text file with the following:

```
10/23/2013  47  34  23  31  03  13  
10/19/2013  33  09  56  54  57  05  
10/16/2013  03  42  26  34  28  27  
10/12/2013  10  58  26  57  08  04
```

I was able to use Scanner and add the dates to an ArrayList "DATE" and I added the rest of the numbers to another ArrayList "NUM" (See Code)

I am Trying to build an ArrayList> "MAIN" or even a HashMap that will hold each line as an Index as follow:

MAIN[[47,34,23,31,03,13],[33,09,56,54,57,05],[03,42,26,34,28,27],[10,58,26,57,08,04]]

I was unable to get the desired result using my code below and I need help restructuring the code to get the desired result

Thank you.

```
   public class Grades {

static String line;
static BufferedReader reader;

static String file = "file/Grades.txt";

static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> MAIN;
static ArrayList<String> NUM ;

static ArrayList<String> DATE ;
static ArrayList rand;

static int index = 0;

public static void main(String args[]) {

    MAIN = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    //lotoNum();



    DATE = new ArrayList<String>();



try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)));

    wwhile(scan.hasNextLine()){
        NUM = new ArrayList<String>();

        String token = scan.nextLine();
        String [] line = token.split("  ");


            DATE.add(line[0]);

            for (int i = 1; i < line.length; i++){
                NUM.add(line[i]);
            }
            MAIN.add(index, NUM);
                index++;


                System.out.println(MAIN);

                //NUM.clear();
                //NUM.trimToSize();


        }


        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
 }
```

THE OUTPUT :
[[47, 34, 23, 31, 03, 13]]
[[47, 34, 23, 31, 03, 13], [33, 09, 56, 54, 57, 05]]
[[47, 34, 23, 31, 03, 13], [33, 09, 56, 54, 57, 05], [03, 42, 26, 34, 28, 27]]
[[47, 34, 23, 31, 03, 13], [33, 09, 56, 54, 57, 05], [03, 42, 26, 34, 28, 27], [10, 58, 26, 57, 08, 04 ]]

Comment: Can you please include both the desired result and the actual result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
int index = 0;

while (scan.hasNextLine()){
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    String[] tokens = line.split("  ");

    // you must create a new list everytime or else they will 
    // reference the same object.  That's why you're getting the output.
    // you are.  Also delete the declareation outside of this loop
    // ArrayList<String> NUM;   ----    NUM = new ArrayLis<String>();

    ArrayList<String> NUM = new ArrayLis<String>();

    DATE.add(tokens[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < tokens.length; i++){
        NUM.add(tokens[i]);
    }

    MAIN.add(index, NUM);
    index++;

    System.out.println(MAIN);

    NUM.clear();


}
```

Comment: I did but the result was: [[10/23/2013, , 47, , 34, , 23, , 31, , 03, , 13, 10/19/2013, , 33, , 09, , 56, , 54, , 57, , 05], [10/23/2013, , 47, , 34, , 23, , 31, , 03, , 13, 10/19/2013, , 33, , 09, , 56, , 54, , 57, , 05]]

Comment: I changed int=0 into int=1 in for loop to remove date and added extra space in split("  "); to remove extra comma and this is the result:    [[47, 34, 23, 31, 03, 13, 33, 09, 56, 54, 57, 05], [47, 34, 23, 31, 03, 13, 33, 09, 56, 54, 57, 05]]

Comment: Edit your post to add the code you have.  I don't know why you're reading two lines.

Comment: NUM is refrencing the same Object. You need to declare NUM inside the loop.  See my edit.

Comment: ok!! I got it, I moved NUM = new ArrayList<String>(); int the while loop and it works1.